# how can i mapping domain for java web application docker container

Tags: docker, nginx

I have a Redhat Linux server In that, I installed docker and run docker containers in it. Now I want to map a domain to docker containers by using Nginx.

What is the correct process to map domains by using Nginx. Install Nginx as a container or Install Nginx in the Host server.

Please Let me Know which one is the best way to map domains. And Share the process document ao any references.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You seem to have asked [several](/q/74599801) [similar](/q/74569483) [questions](/q/74546190) recently.  Could you focus on one of these questions and improve it with enough details to be answerable?  This specific question is on the border of what's acceptable for Stack Overflow (is "map a domain" really a programming problem?) and another site like [sf] or [devops.se] might be a better place to ask.

Comment: For the last few days, I struggled to solve this issue.  No one can respond, so that's why I post multiple times. Anyway thanks for your suggestions.